# Poincaré's Recurrence Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I have been trying for a long time to prove the equality in the middle in the last line [image]

Comment: ... and then... ?

Comment: I could not prove the equality in the middle in the last line

Comment: Note $E \cap G \subset E \cap G_0$ so that $\mu(E\cap G) \leq \mu(E \cap G_0)$. On the other hand, $$\mu(E \cap G_0)-\mu(E \cap G) = \mu((E \cap G_0)\backslash(E \cap G))=\mu(E \cap (G_0 \backslash G))$$$$\leq \mu(G_0 \backslash G) =\mu(G_0)-\mu(G)=0$$where we used $G_0 \subset G$ in the second-to-last equality.